# Error Encountered During Oscar INstallation

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-oscar

I am trying to setup django-oscar using [this][1] guide, however

[1]: https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.4/internals/getting_started.html on running

> python manage.py migrate

I got the following error:

> LookupError: No installed app with label 'communication'

please how can I solve this?

Comment: You're reading the documentation for version 2.0, but trying to set up version 2.1 - there are significant differences between the two. Make sure you use the version of the documentation that matches the version you have installed.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot for your time, this is of great help.

Comment: @AdeoluTemitopeOlofintuyi how did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @ImohRufusAnthony try to create new environment and do fresh setup of oscar on it.